# JQuery and D3.js crash most mobile browsers

Tags: android, jquery, performance, optimization, d3.js

I have a D3.JS and Jquery code that renders a json file into a graph. Each graph is a set of Twitter profile pictures for users. The json file is generated dynamically and retrieved from a specific URL.

This is an example of the Josn file:

```js
{  
   name:"Graph",
   children:[  
      {  
         name:"نفخر_برايتنا_الخضراء",
         children:[  
            {  
               real_name:"Ahmed Al Omran",
               screen_name:"ahmed",
               profile_pic:"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/495355319090810880/giEtljue_normal.jpeg"
            },
            {  
               real_name:"ماجد التويجري",
               screen_name:"Tuwaijrim",
               profile_pic:"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/507953977430790145/BoF8TmIl_normal.jpeg"
            },
            {  
               real_name:"د.حافظ المدلج",
               screen_name:"Hafez_AlMedlej",
               profile_pic:"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/457496447756546049/x-S0HHdM_normal.jpeg"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         name:"شيل_الألف",
         children:[  
            {  
               real_name:"سمير الجنيد",
               screen_name:"SamirJunaid",
               profile_pic:"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/505355564977618944/7sLBmz1a_normal.jpeg"
            },
            {  
               real_name:"تويتر محمد المطيري ",
               screen_name:"m_almutairi",
               profile_pic:"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/491273183597580289/ynZAwSnx_normal.jpeg"
            },
            {  
               real_name:"محماس الرابع طـعش™",
               screen_name:"m7__14",
               profile_pic:"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/494505359487156224/pJkSlhUy_normal.jpeg"
            },
            {  
               real_name:"عبدالمجيد الكناني",
               screen_name:"Abdulmajeed113",
               profile_pic:"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/432559990323552256/GIlFpQ4y_normal.jpeg"
            },
            {  
               real_name:"اِستثنائي",
               screen_name:"1171420",
               profile_pic:"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/512147080538619904/l2Xde2Kp_normal.jpeg"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         name:"عبدالله_القاضي_مفقود_في_لوس_انجلوس",
         children:[  
            {  
               real_name:"فراس بقنه",
               screen_name:"FMB4",
               profile_pic:"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/467237157568913408/beqbB3VC_normal.jpeg"
            },
            {  
               real_name:"د خالد المنيف",
               screen_name:"khalids225",
               profile_pic:"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/507317153746280448/aCjeeuHi_normal.jpeg"
            },
            {  
               real_name:"فهد بن عبدالله البكر",
               screen_name:"Falbaker",
               profile_pic:"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/478487523178450946/Wf1cbofN_normal.jpeg"
            },
            {  
               real_name:"د . سامي الحمود",
               screen_name:"Sami_Alhomood",
               profile_pic:"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/451473568795074560/EMD5DwB-_normal.jpeg"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The javascript code is the following :

```js
var url = "http://URL to JSON";

$(document).ready(function() {

  drawGraph();

  });


function drawGraph(){

var w = 900,

  h = 900,

  r = 900,

  x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, r]),

  y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, r]),

  node,

  root;



var pack = d3.layout.pack()

  .size([r, r])

  .value(function(d) { return 1; });



var vis = d3.select("#content1").insert("svg:svg")

  .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")

  .attr("width", w)

  .attr("height", h);

  

var defs = vis.append("svg:defs");



var g = vis.append("svg:g")

  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w - r) / 2 + "," + (h - r) / 2 + ")");



d3.json(url, function(data) {

  node = root = data;

  

  var nodes = pack.nodes(root);

 

  defs.selectAll("pattern")

 .data(nodes)

 .enter().append("svg:pattern")

 .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "i" + i; })

 .attr("x", "0")

 .attr("y", "0")

 .attr("patternunits", "userSpaceOnUse")

 .attr("width", function(d) { return d.r * 1; })

 .attr("height", function(d) { return d.r * 1; })

 .append("svg:image")

 .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) { return d.profile_pic; })

 .attr("x", "0")

 .attr("y", "0")

 .attr("width", function(d) { return d.r * 2; })

 .attr("height", function(d) { return d.r * 2; });

  

  g.selectAll("circle")

 .data(nodes)

 .enter()

 .append("a")

 .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return !d.name ? "https://twitter.com/search/%23" + d.parent.name + "%20from%3A" + d.screen_name : "#"; })

 .attr("target", function(d) { return !d.children ? "_blank" : "_self"; })

 .append("svg:circle")

 .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return "url(#i" + i + ")"; });

  

  g.selectAll("circle")

 .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })

 .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })

 .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })

 .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });

 

  g.selectAll("rect")

 .data(nodes)

 .enter()

 .append("svg:rect")

 .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })

 .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.x - d.r) + (d.r * 2 * 0.025); })

 .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y - (d.r * 0.40) / 2; })

 .attr("rx", "5")

 .attr("ry", "5")

 .attr("width", function(d) { return (d.r * 2) * 0.95; })

 .attr("height", function(d) { return d.r * 0.40; });



  g.selectAll("text")

 .data(nodes)

 .enter().append("svg:text")

 .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })

 .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })

 .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })

 .attr("dy", ".35em")

 .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

 .style("font-size", function(d) {

   if ((d.r * 2) < 40) {

  return "0.35em";

   } else if ((d.r * 2) >= 40 && (d.r * 2) < 80) {

  return "0.55em";

   } else if ((d.r * 2) >= 80 && (d.r * 2) < 120) {

  return "0.65em";

   } else if ((d.r * 2) >= 120 && (d.r * 2) < 160) {

  return "0.75em";

   } else if ((d.r * 2) >= 160 && (d.r * 2) < 200) {

  return "1.25em";

   } else if ((d.r * 2) >= 200 && (d.r * 2) < 240) {

  return "1.5em";

   } else if ((d.r * 2) >= 280 && (d.r * 2) < 280) {

  return "1.70em";

   } else {

  return "2.0em";

   }

 })

 .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.r > 20 ? 1 : 0; })

 .text(function(d) { return d.name ? d.name : d.real_name; });


  g.select("circle").remove(0); 

  

  g.select("text").remove(0); 

  

  g.select("rect").remove(0); 

  $("#progress").hide();

  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My experience in Javascript and Jquery is not strong. I searched a lot online and came up with few solutions that I couldn't implement, due to my lack of experience: The solutions are:

1. Using Canvas instead of SVG.
2. Render each circle separately and place a delay between them.

I tried to do that but I failed and I hope someone point me in the right direction. Also can this code be optimized in a different way. I hope I included all the necessary information and files. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Do you get any error messages when the browser crashes?  Does it work fine on desktop?  Which specific browsers do/don't work?  How big is the real JSON file? (i.e., how many elements are you creating at once? -- 12 images shouldn't cause a problem, but 120 might!)  Do you really need to have the JQuery library as well as D3? (in this code, you could easily replace it with d3 functions -- it might reduce demands on the device memory to only have one library loaded)?

Comment: It doesn't crash on the desktop browsers. It's used too on old versions of Firefox. I tried android chromecast/firefox and got the same problem. The images aren't a lot. Most of the time, they go up to 60-70 images. I don't about JQuery but the D3 says I needed to include JQuery file. This is a link to JSON file, you might wanna take a look. http://www.twitalaan.com/services/graph.php. This is D3 page, http://www.twitalaan.com/. Thanks